# How to prevent image with srcset to go beyond intrinsic width?

Tags: html, css, image, srcset

Here is the minimal reproducible example:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  height: 100%; /* has to be 100%, no px or em heights */
}

div img {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x225/000/fff" srcset="https://dummyimage.com/300x225/000/fff 600w, https://dummyimage.com/768x568/000/fff 768w">
</div>
```

The problem I have is that the image stretches beyond it's natural dimensions and I need to prevent that.

The aim is to:

- Parent element of the image in full width and height
- Image can't be as `background-image` (SEO)
- Image can't have fixed width and height

Looking only for CSS solutions.

Comment: `object-fit: scale-down` does it in Chrome but not in FF, and I'm not sure Chrome is right...

Comment: `object-fit: scale-down` is a bit buggy in FF, but works :) you can post it as an answer and I will accept it in couple days, if there won't be any better solutions.